# javascript options.length = 0 not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I have a page that sets the length of a select list to 0 before it adds new options.  This worked fine in all browsers until IE9.  In IE9 I get the error: DOM Exception: NOT_FOUND_ERR (8).  This is all I'm trying to do:

```
var typebox = document.sForm.ePosition;
typebox.options.length = 0;
```

Works fine in compatibility mode.

Comment: So basically you're trying to remove all the elements of a select box before adding items? If so, that's not the best way to go about it.

Comment: Ok.  Give me some pointers.  What is another way to go about it?

Comment: See @Seth's answer; you should remove the elements via code.

Answer (score 3):

Try executing each piece in your console, and see where your exception is:

```
document.sForm
document.sForm.ePosition
document.sForm.ePosition.options
document.sForm.ePosition.options.length
```

I tried setting the length of options to 0, and was pretty surprised that it worked (in Chrome). `Array.length` should be a read-only property, in my opinion. I would use DOM code to remove the elements, something like this:

```
while (element.hasChildNodes()) {
    element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: `options` isn't an actual `Array`, but leaving that aside, what's wrong with a writable `length` property on an array? It seems to provide an intuitive and simple way to clear an array to me.

Comment: @Tim: Setting an array's length from say 10 to 5 apparently makes the array shorter, but to me, not in an obvious way. For example, it's clear that you're truncating the array, but are you doing it from the front or back? Maybe the last 5 items that were added? I think it's clearer to use the array mutator methods like `pop`, `push`, etc. Also, length is read only for other objects (like functions). It just doesn't feel like something that should be writable. (I didn't realize it wasn't an actual `Array`).

Comment: Fair enough. I've been dealing with JS arrays for so long I'm not sure I can judge them objectively any more.

Answer (score 3):

I was just struck by the same issue and found a convenient solution for those of us using jQuery:

```
$(selectObject).empty();
```

I've tested this in IE 7-9, FF 10.0 and Chrome 18 using jQuery 1.4.4.

Answer (score 1):

Question was in pure javascript, please supply first a pure javascript reply. The users could not be interested in jquery since many embedded solutions can't use jquery.